# Linux summary a table and sum all columns from each given occurrence

Tags: shell, awk, grep, summary

After finishing an analysis I get a table with a lot of columns and rows. Also, as a new table is written, the number of lines/cols can vary so I am not able to predict how many of each there will be. Every row has an index in column one but those indexes can repeat through the table. So what I want is a grep/awk/bash way to retrieve all those lines with the same index and sum all columns to get just one line with the summed values.
As an illustration:

**table**

```
index,sampleA,sampleB,sampleC
nana,22,12,4
baba,47,4,5
nana,1,5,9
nana,7,5,8
```

**after parsing**

```
index,sampleA,sampleB,sampleC
nana,30,22,21
baba,47,4,5
```

I would appreciate so much if you could help me on that.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little long winded, but something like this will do the job:

```
awk -F"," 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} NR==1{print $0; next} NR>1{sampleA[$1]+=$2; sampleB[$1]+=$3; sampleC[$1]+=$4}END{for (sample in sampleA){print sample, sampleA[sample], sampleB[sample], sampleC[sample]}}' yourfile
```

Explanation:

1. Split each line by a comma `-F","`
2. Before processing the file insure that the output field separator matches the field seperator (a comma) `BEGIN{OFS=FS}`
3. If this is the first line of the file then print it out (it's the header) and then continue to the next line `NR==1{print $0; next}`
4. If this isn't the header line then create three arrays to store the cumulative values from columns 2, 3, 4. The "key" of the arrays is the value in column 1 `NR>1{sampleA[$1]+=$2; sampleB[$1]+=$3; sampleC[$1]+=$4}`
5. Finally at the end, loop through the first of the three arrays (they will all be the same length so we only need to loop one). Then print out the values stored in each one for that key: `END{for (sample in sampleA){print sample, sampleA[sample], sampleB[sample], sampleC[sample]}}`

Comment: Thank you JNveill. I think I am figuring out what the code is doing but could you be so kind as to explain it a little bit? Because it is working for the example table I've posted but it is not for another example table that I am testing here.

Comment: The other table is:
index,sampleA,sampleB,sampleC
nana,2338,0,330221
baba,0,0,46581
nana,0,0,80
nana,0,0,42
baba,10,0,27
caca,8,0,14

running the code only prints the first collumn with no sum:
index,sampleA,sampleB,sampleC
caca,8,0,0
nana,2338,0,0
baba,10,0,0

Comment: I've added an explanation. Not sure why it wouldn't work for that other file though.

Comment: Oh! I see the typo. `sampleC[$1]+=$3` should be $4... Updated the answer. Sorry about that.

Comment: oh yes! I didn't see the typo too. Now it is working

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify the shell, but if you fancy using ksh (93l+), that should also do the trick.

This script makes some assumptions though :

1. There can be any number of column, BUT each line has the same number of column
2. There is no space in the index name
3. There is always a value in each column

   ```
   #!/bin/ksh

   # CSV to input as first argument, CSV to ouput as second argument
   InputCSV=$1
   OutputCSV=$2

   typeset -A Index

   while read line; do
       lineArray=(${line//,/ })
       # Assume that the first column is always named "index", but you can modify this
       if [[ ${lineArray[0]} == "index" ]]; then
           titleArray=(${line//,/ })
           continue
       fi
       for ((i=1;i<${#lineArray[*]};i++)); do
           if [[ -z ${Index[${lineArray[0]}][${titleArray[$i]}]} ]]; then
                   Index[${lineArray[0]}]+=( [${titleArray[$i]}]=${lineArray[$i]} )
           else
                   Index[${lineArray[0]}][${titleArray[$i]}]=$(( ${Index[${lineArray[0]}][${titleArray[$i]}]} + ${lineArray[$i]} ))
           fi
       done
   done < $InputCSV

   exec 3>$OutputCSV

   titleBar=${titleArray[0]}
   for ((i=1;i<${#titleArray[*]};i++)); do
       titleBar+=",${titleArray[$i]}"
   done

   print $titleBar >&3

   for j in ${!Index[@]}; do
       outLine=$j
       for ((i=1;i<${#titleArray[*]};i++)); do
               outLine+=",${Index[$j][${titleArray[$i]}]}"
       done
       print $outLine >&3
   done

   exec 3>&-
   ```

Comment: Thanks Andre. That is a pretty nice code but I have bash shell. I'll try to convert it to bash if possible.

Comment: Actually, won't be possible. I'm using multidimensional arrays here which are not supported by bash. Oh well, was a fun little project anyway :) . Thanks for the question.

Comment: In case, my mistake.. I should have specified "bash" instead of "shell" in the question. Will be carefull the next times